# How to adjust plot size when running R code from Rmarkdown .Rmd files in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: r, r-markdown, jupyter-lab

I am Running **R code** Rmarkdown `.Rmd` files in **jupyter lab**.

(doing this as I have an old machine that gets really slow with R studio and it becomes a pain sometimes to work in Rstudio but Jupyter still works lightning fast).

**Issue** I am facing is in controlling the dimensions of output chart.

Usually for Python one can control dimensions by using matplotlib (`plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)`) etc. and in **Rstudio** by chunk options with `fig.width & fig.height`.

But how can I control the Chart output size when running Rmarkdown file in Jupyter Lab. (I mean controlling the output window of Jupyter)

I have tried adding `{fig.height = 14}` in the plot cell but that didn't help either.

Is there a way to set plot sizes of jupyter lab or ggplot ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using `options(repr.plot.width = 14, repr.plot.height = 8)`

Found the answer on: https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/105201